# Why the "document.addEventListener('keydown', function (x) {....} doesn't show on the browser (live reload enabled) the keyboardEvent

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am new to javascript and I am experimenting with the below code:

`

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (x){
    console.log(x.key);
  });
```

`

I would expect to see on my live reload browser (Microsoft Edge - Windows 10) under developer tools - Console the KeyboardEvent with the Key: , the code: etc. But unfortunately, nothing happened.

Comment: The code works as it is, make sure you haven't filtered logs out of the console output.

Comment: Hi Teemu, thank you for your answer. No, I haven't filtered logs out of the console output.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue that I was facing. I wasn't actually selecting the live browser window when I was pressing a key, and that is why I wasn't getting the property of the key.